# Copying resources on build in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my project I have a resource file named devices.json that I maintain outside of the project to ensure consistency between different projects. So I only have the file added as a link with:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\..\resources\devices.json" Link="devices.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

The file gets copied to the build folder correctly but asp.net core projects seem to run with the project root directory set as the Working Dir. So if I try to read the file with `File.ReadAllText("devices.json")` it will throw a FileNotFound exception.

Is there a way to copy the devices.json file to the project root dir on build so it will be accessible without hardcoding paths to the dev output dir?

Id rather avoid having to write
string text;

```
if(env.IsDevelopment())
{
  text = File.ReadAllText("bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\devices.json");
}
else
{
  text = File.ReadAllText("bin\\Release\\netcoreapp2.1\\devices.json");
}
```

And even if I did, this will break as soon as i publish the project since then the entire project will be copied to the Publish dir which will then run as the CurrentWorking dir.

Any sugestions on how to solve this?

Comment: It sounds to me like you have a setting that runs your code from the project directory.   The code will normally be executed from the debug\netcoreapp2.1 folder.  If you right click on the project, click properties, click Debug tab, check 'Working directory'.  It should be empty.

Comment: @Neil Based on your comment I went back to check if I hade any settings messed up but I couldn't find any. So I created a new project from scratch to check the default working dir, but I got the same result. Environment.WorkingDirectory is by default set to the project root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a build target in your project file to copy it across:

```
  <Target Name="copyDevices" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="../../resources/devices.json" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
  </Target>
```

Then use the following to read the file within your web app:

```
            var test = File.ReadAllText(
    Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "devices.json")
);
```

[image]

Comment: Using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory did solve my problem and works when deploying to docker too. So thank you for that. But I'm not sure what the Target directive is supposed to do that the Content Include didn't already accomplish. It just copies the file to the build folder, right?

Answer (score -1):

`text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "devices.json"));`